# the proof of implicit function theorem (Terence Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Implicit function theorem: Let $E$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable, and let $y = ( y_1, ... , y_n)$ be a point in $E$ such that $f(y) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_n}}(y) \not= 0$. Then there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ containing $(y_1, ... , y_{n-1})$, an open subset $V$ of $E$ containing $y$, and a function $g : U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(y_1, ... ,y_{n-1}) = y_n$, and 
$$\{(x_1, ... ,x_n) \in V : f(x_1, ... ,x_n) = 0\} = \{(x_1, ... ,x_{n-1}, g(x_1, ... ,x_{n-1}) : (x_1, ... ,x_n) \in U\}.$$ 
Moreover, $g$ is differentiable at $(y_1, ... ,y_{n-1})$, and we have 
$$\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x_j}}(y_1, ... , y_{n-1}) = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_j}}(y)/ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_n}}(y)$$
for all $1 \le j \le n-1$. 
[image]
[image]

I don't understand some steps in the proof. I highlight with purple lines the step I am struggling with.

1. The author let $F^{-1} (x) = (h_1(x), ..., h_n(x))$. Since $F$ is invertible, $x = F(h_1(x), ... ,h_n(x))$, but why $h_j(x) = x_j$?
2. We know that $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but how do we know that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?
3. Similarly, we know that $h_n$ is differentiable at $(y_1, ... ,y_{n-1}, 0)$, but how can we prove that $g$ is differentiable at $(y_1, ... ,y_{n-1})$?

I really appreciate if you give some help!

Comment: 1. Follows from the definition of $F$ and the fact that it is one-to-one. 2. The $W$ is the homeomorphic image of the open set $V$, hence it is open. 3. The $g$ is a restriction of a differentiable function hence is differentiable.

Comment: This (coordinate form, finite-dimensional) is a difficult way to approach the Implicit and Inverse Function Theorems.

I recommend the simple, straightforward, and *coordinate-free* formulations of these theorems given in V. Arnol'd's "Ordinary Differential Equations".  As for proofs, Arnol'd begins by proving the Inverse Function Theorem (from which the Implicit one is later inferred), essentially following the approach of https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Calculus-Normed-Spaces-Analysis/dp/154874932X/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=9781548749323&linkCode=qs&qid=1607107411&s=books&sr=1-1

Answer (score 2):

1. 

$$(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) = x = F(F^{-1}(x)) = F((h_1(x), \ldots, h_j(x), \ldots, h_n(x))) = (h_1(x), \ldots, h_j(x), \ldots, f(h_1(x), \ldots, h_n(x)))$$
Therefore $x_j = h_j(x)$.

2. Theorem 2.1.5 (c) states that if $f$ is a continuous function then the inverse image/preimage of an open set is also open. We can make a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that maps $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$ to $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, 0)$. By that theorem,
   $$f^{-1}(W) = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \vert f((x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})) = (x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, 0) \in W\} = U$$
   is open as $W$ is open.
3. The derivative of $g$ evaluated at $(y_1, \ldots, y_{n-1})$ is the derivative of $h_n$ evaluated at $(y_1, \ldots, y_{n-1}, 0)$ which exists.

Answer (score 1):

1) From the definition of $F$, it fixes the first $n-1$ coordinates

2) $U$ is basically the intersection of the hyperplane $x_n=0$ and $W$, and this intersection is open in the hyperplane (which you identify as $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$)

3) Composing a differentiable function with a linear projection gives you a differentiable function (at least, I think, it should be easy to prove using linearity and the definition of differentiability)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand the statement that the intersection is open in the hyperplane. Could you give some more detail?

Comment: Well, I am actually not really strong in topology, but if you consider the subset topology of that hyperplane, then that topology should coincide with the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Since $W$ is the intersection of your subset and the open set $U$, then $W$ is by definition open. What you have here is, however, stronger. You don’t have a generic subset, but an hyperplane, and its vector space structure (euclidean, actually) can give you a topology as it is (I mean, not viewing it as a subset of some sort). These two topologies should coincide (it should be easy to prove, I think)

Comment: Sorry if it is confusing, I am not really well versed in these topics, and I may have said something wrong